# In matlab is cell array of cell arrays equivalent to list of list

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I'm trying to implement functionality in matlab where I need the equivalent data structure to a list of lists. Based on what I have found is a cell array of cell arrays a good equivalent in matlab.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, roughly...  With the exception that lists are sequential-access and cell-arrays are random-access.  *ie* the cell-array is in fact an array, not a list.  I don't think there is a list analogue in MatLab, so this is the closest you'll get.

Comment: could you please vote to reopen this question. Some of the people who voted to close this question seem to have no expertise in this area.

Comment: I could, but it might not be worthwhile.  This community can get a bit anal about how questions are asked.  I generally take a more patient and open approach and am used to reading between the lines, but I have spent several years as a lab tutor while I was at varsity.  Not everyone here has that kind of social exposure.  The question was not well formulated, but I think it was a fair question to ask.